# Issue using fixed positioning on popup

Tags: html, css, popup

So, I've got this issue one a project I'm working on where position fixed won't work on a popup that shows up after pressing a button. The problem occurs on mobile viewports only since the popup is only shown on mobile devices.

The problem is that I need the popup to have a fixed position so that it wil allways remain in the middle of the users screen no matter where they are on the page.

The link to my webpage is: http://bayron.nl/recepten-toevoegen-template.html

If you resize it to a mobile size and scroll down to a dropdown looking button (image below) and click that. You'll be able to see the popup that uses fixed positioning but it does not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `position` to get it.
Use below css to get the same.

```css
body, html {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.box {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.popup {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:200px; /* Change as your requirement */
  height:200px;  /* Change as your requirement */
  background:#fff;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="popup">
      popup
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but it's still not working. Any other suggestions? Maybe you could look at the code to see what's wrong if that's not to much to ask for? Thanks!

Comment: Then post relevant code for the same.. like working fiddle or snippet